# Why isn't my public folder fetching files for '/' URL in my NodeJS App?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I am trying to place static files in my public folder such as the html,css and js files but they won't fetch to the get url ('/').
Here is my folder structure

```
app.js
node_modules
--express
package.json
public
--style.css
```

My app is:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('<html><head><link href=assets/style.css type=text/css rel=stylesheet/></head><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>');
});

app.get('/person/:id', function(req, res){
    res.send('<html><head></head><body><h1>Person: ' + req.params.id + '</h1></body></html>');
});

app.get('/api', function(req, res){
    res.json({ firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Doe' });
});

app.listen(port);
```

Style code is:

```
 style.css:
 body {
       font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-sarif;   
}
```

Comment: Where did `assets/` come from in your HTML?

Comment: Your question is not clear, what do you mean with `but they won't fetch to the get url ('/')`. Do you mean that if you put `assets/style.css`  prefixed with your host into the adressbar of your browser then you don't see the content of your css file? What message is shown to you instead?

Comment: @t.niese He forgot to use double quotes so that the browser won't load the CSS file.

Comment: @NidhinDavid the quotes (you can either use `"` or `'`)  are optional in this given example because the value of the attribute does not contain any character that requires quoting. [W3C: 4.4. Attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes) `[...]an unquoted attribute value has the following restrictions: must not contain any literal space characters, must not contain any """, "'", "=", ">", "<", or "\`", characters, must not be the empty string[...]`

Comment: @t.niese He didn't use any of them!!

Comment: @NidhinDavid exactly the value does not contain any of those characters, and as of that it is valid to not use quotes around the value here.

Comment: @t.niese Well...some how when I used the quotes it worked for me. I tried it out in Node 3.3.1  and Google Chrome.Please see my answer

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is, because

```
<link href=assets/style.css type=text/css rel=stylesheet/>
```

is equal to

```
<link href=assets/style.css type=text/css rel="stylesheet/">
```

If you don't use quotes then the value is terminated by one of the following characters: `"`, `'`, `=`, `>`, `<`, or `` ` `` (See [W3C: 4.4. Attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes) for more details).  As of that your value is terminated by the `>` value is `stylesheet/`.

Because of that the `rel`  of your `link` is `stylesheet/`  instead of `stylesheet` and thats why no stylesheet is loaded.

So either you have to add a space between `stylesheet` and `/`:

```
<link href=assets/style.css type=text/css rel=stylesheet />
```

or you need to use quotes.

Comment: That explains the bug. Good job

Answer (score 0):

Can you rename "public" to "assets", then use...

```
app.use(express.static('assets'));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax error in your HTML statement that links to the CSS file. You forgot to enclose the values in double quotes.

Please use the following format:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.css">
```

If you are using ES6 supporting Node.JS then you can use the back-ticks(``) to better format the inline HTML code like:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send(`
        <html>
        <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </body>
        </html>`
        );
});
```

Comment: They are optional in this case: [W3C: 4.4. Attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes) `[...]an unquoted attribute value has the following restrictions: must not contain any literal space characters, must not contain any """, "'", "=", ">", "<", or "\`", characters, must not be the empty string[...]`